# How spark executes code written in non Structured API?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Im new to spark, and as far as I can understand spark executes the code written in **Structured API(dataframes, datasets, and SQL)** in parallel in workers nodes.

Does the same thing also apply to the code written in **NON Structered API**, for example I have this code, which renames files in the S3 bucket:

```
public static boolean renameAwsFolder(String sourceBucketName, String destinationBucketName) {
            System.out.println("Invoked");
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                  AmazonS3 s3client = getAmazonS3ClientObject();
                  List<S3ObjectSummary> fileList = s3client.listObjects(sourceBucketName).getObjectSummaries();
                  //some meta data to create empty folders start
                  ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                  metadata.setContentLength(0);
                  for (S3ObjectSummary file : fileList) {
                        String key = file.getKey();
                        if (key.contains("sitemap/part-")) {
                              System.out.println("Key : " + key);
                              String oldFileName = key.substring(key.indexOf("-") + 1); //part-xxxx
                              String newFileName = "sitemap_" + oldFileName.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "") + ".xml";
                              String destinationKeyName = "output/" + newFileName;
                              CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest =
                                  new CopyObjectRequest(sourceBucketName, file.getKey(), destinationBucketName,
                                      destinationKeyName);
                              s3client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
                        }

                  }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
      }
```

I don't understand is this function going to be executed in parallel in multiple workers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided doesn't use Spark API at all (neither structured nor non-structured) - it's direct AWS S3 operations via the AWS SDK, so it's gonna be exectuted as standard Java code on one-thread on JVM, not in parallel on multiple workers.

Comment: Thanks very much for clarification! I was wondering is there any way to make spark job atomic?